# How can I force rust to format hexadecimal and other non-base-10 integers correctly?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print a negative integer in hexadecimal notation, but can't manage to get rust to automatically print the negative sign. The following code illustrates the problem ([link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca1e5a8107bd764ba19344979b3dbb86) to the playpen):

```
fn main() {
    let x = i8::from_str_radix("-80", 16).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(x, -0x80);
    println!("{:x}!", x as i8);
}
```

When ran, this code writes `80!` to `stdout` rather than the expected -80. I've tried to add the `+` sign flag but the output remained incorrect (in fact, it prepends an incorrect '+' sign!). As far as I can tell, this issue affects every base except 10. Rust's official [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/) makes no mention of this quirk.

My questions are:

1. Is this intended behavior?
2. If it is indeed intended, then is it possible to force rust's formatter to print a negative sign? (to avoid having to handle this as a special case).

Comment: That happens because `0x80` is a special value, since `-0x80 as u8 == 0x80`. Try with any another value, and you'll see that's the two's complement that is formatted.

Comment: Put another way, the `x` formatting will convert signed values to unsigned.

Comment: To clarify @PeterHall's comment, as per the documentation: "For primitive signed integers (i8 to i128, and isize), negative values are formatted as the two’s complement representation."

Comment: It seems this behavior is documented in the `Binary`, `Octal`, `LowerHex`, and `UpperHex` traits directly rather than in the expected module-level documentation `std::fmt` as  @mcarton pointed out. Thank you everyone for your input.